# Visual Studio Cordova app on local/remote IOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, cordova

I am developing mobile app on VS cordova and it is ON windows machine. I have MAC for simulation. All simulations work fine on MAC.

But I can NOT get the app into Iphone 5 for testing using the MAC. I have apple developer account and created a certificate, registered and provisioned the device. When I go Xcode, I can see the provisioned device.

But, when run from VS (windows machine) as a remote device (Iphone is connected to MAC), get an error

“code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4”

Can someone provide some guidance how to deploy my app to Iphone for testing?

I've already follow through the visual guidance. but did not help

Thank you So much

Comment: You are not alone in asking a [cordova] and [ios] questions. I don't mean to be rude here, wwhat has you convinced that developing for the iOS platform is worth development costs? I mean, are you sure that [all this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html) is going to be worth the time, considering the native apps that exist in the app store? There are many iOS users, but there are also Android, Windows, Linux users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I assume the "remotebuild" is working fine with Simulator.

Make sure the device(iPhone 5) has verified provisioning.
iPhone --> Setting --> General --> Profiles --> Select the Provisioning profile

If it is verified then You may want to revoke your provisioning profile and certificate and re-create the provisiong profile.

Make sure the Bundle ID is identical as your Project ID in config.xml file.

Hope this fix the problem.